# How to configure SearchBox

Tags: 2013, search, wiki

I have a problem with my search box in SharePoint 2013 (upper right side).

If I try to search something, it shows me all "global" answers of SharePoint.
This is correct for me because I have some keywords in Tasks, Wiki and Documents.

My problem is now:

If I click on Wiki and try to search the same Keyword again, it shows me again all global results.

But when I am on the Wiki website,  I need to only show the Wiki results.

So:

- On Wiki = only wiki results.
- On Tasks = only task results.
- On Documents = only document results.
- And on "Home" Page of SharePoint = all results.

Is it possible to configure this?
If yes a little walkthrough would be nice.

---

EDIT:
thank you very much for your fast reply. The Search Setting of DropDown is really the point which i am searching for, but i tried it maybe 1-2 days before and it kills the drop down for all of the other scopes like "People", "Conversations", etc...

Or was only my settings wrong?....

About the Result Sources i tried it with the Result Generator on site collection. But i got wrong results back if i type my keywords in the search box.

Hmmm any other ideas or guides?

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to know: Result Sources and Search Settings

Result Sources are what used to be Search Scopes in SP2010. You can define them on site collection or subsite level.

Search Settings define which dropdown items you have in your search dropdown.

So: For every subsite you need to define a Result Source (e.g. Tasks Result Source on Tasks site, Documents Result Source on document site), or you create them globally.
On every subsite you change the Search Settings to include your result source as default.

Some pictures and more information here: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-search-settings-and-search-box-drop-down-menu